# Multiple File uploads using .ashx

Tags: file-upload, upload, uploadify, swfupload, image-upload

I have been looking at this for several days now with no success.  I am trying to create a multi-file upload system for a website.  I have tried several jQuery plugins, including SWFUpload and Uploadify.  Everything works except for the actual upload; the uploaded files never save to the folder.  I'm guessing its the way I am using the .ashx, so any direction on whats wrong with the following code is appreciated.  Thanks,

```
//Jquery is inherited, and I'm pretty sure this is all correct
<link href="/_uploadify/uploadify.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.4.min.js"></script>

//Again, this all works as expected.  CSS displays, SWF works, the issue I THINK deals
//with 'script' and 'folder'.  My Upload.ashx is in the root, as well as uploads folder
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("here");
    $('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'uploader': '/_uploadify/uploadify.swf',
        'script': 'Upload.ashx',
        'cancelImg': '/_uploadify/cancel.png',
        'folder': 'uploads',
        'multi': true,
        'auto': true
    });
});
</script>

<input id="file_upload" name="file_upload" type="file" />

//My handler code, I'm not sure if this works or not but I do know that if
//I try to debug nothing ever fires... I'm sure that's part of the problem
<%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="Upload" %>

using System;
using System.Web;
using System.IO;

public class Upload : IHttpHandler {

public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpPostedFile file = context.Request.Files["Filedata"];

    file.SaveAs("C:\\" + file.FileName);

    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("Hello World");
}

public bool IsReusable
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
```

That's everything I have.  If I try to upload a file with SWFUpload jQuery it says it succeeds but nothing ever saves to the folder.  If I try with Uploadify it fails with either an HTTP Error or IO Error, and again, nothing saves.  Thanks for any and all help.

Comment: Is your ashx files in a member area or something? It might be a session issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out after some more time and debugging.  The issue was actually with Form Authentication and occurred on any pages after the login screen. Here is the fix...

**Add one of the below snippets to the web.config**

If you aren't worried about any authentication try

```
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
```

If you only want to allow access to the new handler, do this

```
<location path="_handlers/Upload.ashx">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="*"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
</location>
```

After I did this the debug points I had in my handler file were getting hit and I was able to solve the rest from there.